# Criação de trigger que ajude a somar um campo consoante uma operacao

Tags: mysql, trigger

Boas colegas. Estou com o seguinte problema, preciso que quando uma ação de inserção de empréstimo seja disparada para a tabela `emp_emprestimo` automaticamente seja feito um update na tabela chamada `genero_frequencia_emprestimos` onde temos unicamente duas tuplas definidas para o genero masculino e o genero femenino dependendo do género do utente que fez o empréstimo na tupla e somar +1 no campo `gef_numeroutentes`. Porém o genero do utente apenas esta registado na tabela ute_utente. Como poderei realizar esta operação?
tentei usar o trecho de código abaixo mais não resultou, porém o mysql aceitou o código mas na inserção de empréstimo deu erro:

```
create trigger update_frequencia_emp_generoMasc after insert on emp_emprestimo for each row update genero_frequencia_emprestimos set gef_numeroutentes=gef_numeroutentes + 1 where gef_id=1 and new.emp_utenteid.ute_genero="M";
```

abaixo deixo o código das tabelas:
Tabela de utentes:

```
CREATE TABLE `ute_utente` (
  `ute_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ute_nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ute_dataNascimento` date NOT NULL,
  `ute_genero` enum('F','M') NOT NULL,
  `ute_naturalidade` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ute_bi` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `ute_nomePai` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ute_nomeMae` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ute_localTrabalho` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ute_contacto` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ute_estado` enum('Não permitido','Permitido') NOT NULL,
  `ute_numeroEmps` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ute_dataRegisto` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ute_instituicaoId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ute_enderecoId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ute_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ute_bi_UNIQUE` (`ute_bi`),
  KEY `ute_instituicaoId` (`ute_instituicaoId`),
  KEY `ute_enderecoId` (`ute_enderecoId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ute_utente_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`ute_instituicaoId`) REFERENCES `ins_instituicaoensino` (`ins_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ute_utente_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`ute_enderecoId`) REFERENCES `ute_endereco` (`ute_enderecoid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Tabela de emprestimos:

```
CREATE TABLE `emp_emprestimo` (
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_utenteId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_livroId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_dataRegisto` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`),
  KEY `emp_utenteId` (`emp_utenteId`),
  KEY `emp_livroId` (`emp_livroId`),
  CONSTRAINT `emp_emprestimo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_utenteId`) REFERENCES `ute_utente` (`ute_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `emp_emprestimo_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_livroId`) REFERENCES `liv_livro` (`liv_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

tabela onde deve acontecer a operação

```
CREATE TABLE `genero_frequencia_emprestimos` (
  `gef_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gef_genero` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gef_numeroUtentes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `gef_numeroVezes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`gef_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Ayrton, você pode fazer um `select into` para pegar o gênero na tabela `ute_utente` e então comparar no `IF` se é masculino (M) ou feminio (F).

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_frequencia_emp_generoMasc after insert on emp_emprestimo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE genero_ varchar(2); 
   select genero into genero_ from ute_utente where ute_id = new.emp_utenteId; 
   IF genero_ = 'M' THEN 
        update genero_frequencia_emprestimos set gef_numeroutentes=gef_numeroutentes + 1 where gef_id=1; 
   ELSEIF genero_ = 'F' THEN 
        update genero_frequencia_emprestimos set gef_numeroutentes=gef_numeroutentes + 1 where gef_id=2; 
   END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: Tentei adaptar o código ao meu mas não deu certo, deu um erro..

Comment: @AyrtonPereira não precisa adaptar o código, só entender a ideia, na sua trigger vc faz um select na tabela onde tem o gênero para ver se é masculino ou feminino, e então faz o update de acordo com cada gênero.